# I am getting this error. When I try to sign in with facebook to my app : There is an error in logging you into this application

Tags: android

I am getting this error. When I try to sign in with facebook to my app. When I  authentication through web it will correctly working but authentication through facebook App it will not working.
Am Using This Query , Release Hash Key will be generated but not working getting error.
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\keytool.exe" -exportcert -alias mrajapaksa -keystore D:\KeyStore\MahindaRajapaksa\mrajapaksa.jks | D:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | D:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl base64

Debug mode it will be working currently but release mode getting error.